# How do I set a maven project property with a groovy script run with gmavenplus?

Tags: maven, groovy, pom.xml, gmavenplus

I have a pom file that uses a property that I'd like to set within an external groovy script. This groovy script needs some existing properties to determine what to set the new property is, but, when I set the property `bindPropertiesToSeparateVariables` to false (within the script execution), all the necessary properties are exposed to the groovy script, but I am unable to set  my new property (`project.properties.setProperty('myproperty', value)` complains about 'project' not existing, and `properties.setProperty('myproperty', value)` doesn't work). When I set `bindPropertiesToSeparateVariables` to true, not all the necessary properties are exposed to the groovy script (`project.properties` does not have all the properties), but I can set my new property using `project.properties.setProperty('myproperty', value)` and it is set successfully.

I am a bit confused as to what exactly `bindPropertiesToSeparateVariables` does, because the description of the property is basically just restating what is already in the name of the property. I tried using `parent.properties` but that didn't work. Can I manually define the properties in the plugin's configuration (right above where the script is executed) and then access them with `project.properties`? If that worked, what if new properties are added that I didn't manually define like that? Does `session.properties` work?

Here is part of my pom file where the script is executed. The last line is where I need to access my new property.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>com.example.group</groupId>
        <artifactId>example-parent-pom</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
        <relativePath>../../..</relativePath>
    </parent>

    <groupId>com.example.group</groupId>
    <artifactId>example.artifact.id</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <properties>
        <someOtherProperty>someValue</someOtherProperty>
        <anotherProperty>anotherValue</anotherProperty>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/sql</outputDirectory>
                    </configuration>
                    <executions>
                        <!-- copy the basescript groovy files so they are accessible on the classpath during script execution -->
                        <execution>
                            <id>Copy basescripts</id>
                            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/classes/</outputDirectory>
                                <resources>
                                    <resource>
                                        <directory>${basedir}/../../../config/build/scripts</directory>
                                        <includes>
                                            <include>**/*.groovy</include>
                                        </includes>
                                    </resource>
                                </resources>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                        <execution>
                            <id>Copy some of the scripts we use</id>
                            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/classes/</outputDirectory>
                                <resources>
                                    <resource>
                                        <directory>${basedir}/../scripts</directory>
                                        <includes>
                                            <include>**/SomeScriptWeUse.groovy</include>
                                            <include>**/SomeOtherScriptWeUse.groovy</include>
                                        </includes>
                                    </resource>
                                </resources>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>resources</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.gmavenplus</groupId>
                <artifactId>gmavenplus-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <allowSystemExits>true</allowSystemExits>
                    <skip>someValue</skip>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>set-myProperty</id>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>execute</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <scripts>
                                <script>file:///${basedir}/../scripts/setMyProperty.groovy</script>
                            </scripts>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.example.another.group.id</groupId>
                <artifactId>homemade-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <skip>${someSkipProp}</skip>
                    <verbose>true</verbose>
                    <forceRemove>true</forceRemove>
                    <someVersionProp>1</someVersionProp>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>Just another execution</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>some-goal</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <someProperty>${myProperty}</someProperty>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
```

Any suggestions are welcome. Please let me know if more information is needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can keep `bindPropertiesToSeparateVariables` set to false and replace `properties.setProperty('myproperty', value)` with `project.properties.setProperty('myproperty', value)`. Then, to access the property further down in the pom file, reference it as `${myproperty}`. Don't define `<myproperty>value</myproperty` anywhere in the pom file or this will not work.